# Hive Solr Storage handler Httpclient error

Tags: hadoop, solr, hive, httpclient

I developed Hive solrCloud storage handler, when I run select statement hive is throwing below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
>
> Exception Details:
>
> Location:
>       org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @62: areturn
>
> Reason:
>
> Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)
>
> Current Frame:
>       bci: @62
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams', 'org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager', 'org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams', 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
>       stack: { 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
>
> Bytecode:
>
> 0000000: bb00 0359 2ab7 0004 4db2 0005 b900 0601
>
> 0000010: 0099 001e b200 05bb 0007 59b7 0008 1209
>
> 0000020: b600 0a2c b600 0bb6 000c b900 0d02 00bb
>
> 0000030: 0011 592b b700 124e 2d2c b800 102d b0
>
> Stackmap Table:
>       append_frame(@47,Object[#127]) 
>     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.(CloudSolrClient.java:189)

Is there any jar I need to update in class path?

PS: I don't have write access to add any jar in Hadoop or hive lib directory.
System configuration:
Hive 0.13, solrcloud 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7948) for **solrj httpclient** version conflict. The root cause of this issue is httpclient library version conflict in hadoop class path. The solrj client is not getting initialized by right version of httpclient. 
Initializing solrj client with default Httpclient should resolve this issue.
e.g.

```
SystemDefaultHttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
this.server = new CloudSolrClient(url,httpClient);
```

You can export hadoop class path to add additional jar files to classpath. Check [blog](http://www.techsquids.com/bd/hive-hadoop-jar-files-conflicts/) for adding jars to mapreduce job classpath.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/xxx/noggit-0.6.jar:/xxx/httpclient-4.5.1.jar
```